# Monotone characteristic function

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

Let $X$ be a continuous, symmetric random variable such that its characteristic function $\phi_X$ is real, symmetric and with $\lim_{t\to\infty}\phi_X(t)=0$.
What other properties must $X$ have in order to guarantee that $\phi_X$ is monotone in the interval $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Most of the time, the characteristic function takes complex values, nor just real ones. Thus the notion of monotonicity is not defined. Are you only considering random variables for which the characteristic function is real (i.e. that have a hermitian symmetry)?

Comment: Yeah, if $X$ is symmetric (that is $X\overset{dist}=-X$, then $\phi_X$ is real and symmetric (that is $\phi_X(t)=\phi_X(-t)$). I am assuming that $X$ is symmetric and continuous (that is absolutely continuous or singular continuous wrt the Lebesgue measure) and moreover that $\phi_X$ goes to zero (which is not always the case when $X$ is continuous).

Comment: This post on MathOverflow shows that a sufficient condition would be for $X$ to have a density that's completely monotone. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379678/when-are-fourier-coefficients-monotonic

Comment: Their problem seems different, no? They only care about the values of the Fourier transform at the integers. Moreover in my question neither the density (assuming there is a density) nor the characteristic function can be periodic.

Comment: What they have seems easily transposable to the case of the Fourier transform. The assumption of complete monotonicity gives a "Laplace transform" (exponential) form to the distribution, and then they change the order of integrals to show a monotonic form for the characteristic function.